# What's the function of the "|" (pipe) operator?

Tags: javascript, operators

I have this line that I copied from another place:

```
Total += parseFloat($(this).val())|0;
```

What's the function of the operator `|`? When I change the number, I get different results.

Comment: MDN has a JavaScript reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference#Operators_and_other_keywords

Comment: hi, thanks for all te answers, just to note, when the input field value was "3.5" the funcion return "3", when I change "0" and put "2", i get "5" ... in total variable... I assume it was som position related parameter ...

Comment: @Nicolas400: Someone upvoted my answer (the accepted answer), which made me look at it to remind myself what it was, and I was unhappy to find it was *wrong*. It said `|0` would be like `Math.floor`, which is only true for positive numbers. Fixed, FYI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `|` in JavaScript is an [integer bitwise OR operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.10). In that context, it strips off any fractional portion returned by `parseFloat`. The expression `parseFloat($(this).val())` will result in a number with (potentially) a fractional component, but then `|0` will [convert it to an integer number](http://es5.github.com/#x9.5), OR it with `0` (which means it won't change), and so the overall result is to get a whole number.

So functionally, it *truncates* the fractional portion off the number. `-1.5` becomes `-1`, and `1.5` becomes `1`. This is like `Math.floor`, but truncating rather than rounding "down" (`Math.floor(-1.5)` is `-2` — the next *lowest* whole number — rather than `-1` as the `|0` version gives us).

So perhaps that's why it was used, to chop off (rather than "floor") the fractional portion of the number.

Alternately, it could be a typo. The author of that code *might* have meant to write this (note `||` rather than `|`):

```
Total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
```

That defends against the possibility that `$(this).val()` returns `""` or similar, resulting in `parseFloat` returning `NaN`. It uses [the curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to return `0` rather than `NaN` in that case. (And there's an advertisement for *putting spaces around your operators*.) Would have to know the context of the code to say whether truncating to a whole number (`|`) makes sense when adding to `Total`, or if they were just defending the `NaN` case.

Comment: What are some instances where it is helpful to use bitwise operators?

Comment: @Jasper: There are all sorts of times you want bitwise operators, this is just an unusual use of one.

Comment: It also converts `NaN` to `0`, and makes sure the `.val()` is evaluated as a decimal, where `parseInt` would need the extra radix arg.

Comment: @amnotiam: LOL, I was just editing my answer to mention `NaN`, but in relation to `||` rather than `|`.

Answer (score 3):

The `|` operator in javascript is the bitwise or operator

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

This operator treats the operands as 32 bit integers and for every bit returns 1 if either is 1 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: How it convert the operands to 32 bit integers?

Comment: @Shiplu: It's defined in the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x9.5 (which does not mean that browsers really do it that way).

Comment: @Shiplu i'm not exactly sure how it does that. Likely converts them first to numbers and then rounds to 32 bit integers.

Comment: @Shiplu: Yes, it converts it to a 32-bit integer (http://es5.github.com/#x9.5) -- temporarily, for the calculation. Then the 32-bit integer is converted back to an IEEE 64-bit float (the only kind of numbers that JavaScript has, except for temporary integers during calculations like this one), but at that point the fractional part has been removed (e.g., `Math.floor`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also though the result is float.